# put custom css in vue.js/webpack

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to link my css to my vue.js file. I was building this out without the webpack. So I had many style worked out.. However, when I decided to move it to a webpack none of my custom css is even calling. I did research that said to include the css in the index.html as a link so that is what I have done. Is there a better way to do this that I didn't see? Any help would be much appreciated. It is also worth mentioning that I tried to use Include in the App.vue as well as require as I had seen in other suggestions but both pulled up errors and refused to compile any of my files....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= webpackConfig.output.publicPath %>favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/assets/css/main.css">
    <title>my-project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but my-project doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <p>this is test script</p>

    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in main.js or application.js, add like this `import './assets/css/main.css'`

Comment: Haven't you tried merely `import './path/to/your/file.css`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you!